# Is there a way to change the way the dragging of a function works?

Tags: excel

I am trying to autofill cells with functions by dragging the first function I have down a lot of cells.

Currently, I have this function:

```
=IF(A30=A2,A2,"")
```

and when I drag, it becomes this:

```
=IF(A31=A3,A3,"")
```

but I want this:

```
=IF(A31=A2,A2,"")
```

I tried typing in a view previous boxes and then dragging the formula, however, then it just jumps to totally different conclusions that I don't want.

I also have a similar issue where I am copy pasting formulas, and I want it to keep the same column for one value, but not for the other:

Copied:

```
=IF(N7="","",B6)
```

Pasted Result:

```
=IF(P7="","",D6)
```

Wanted Pasted Result:

```
=IF(P7="","",B6)
```

Anything would help. Otherwise, I have to go through 40 columns by 200 rows by hand. Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between relative, absolute, row absolute, and column absolute references in Excel formulas? This is all fairly standard. You could read through a tutorial. What you are seeing is the default relative references. You can override the defaults.

Comment: Thanks man! I had no idea about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$` signs before the column and/or the row to achieve what you want. Your first example:

```
=IF(A31=A$2, A$2, "")
```

Comment: Oh my god why did I not know about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the row of the original A2 with a *$* like `A$2`.

```
=IF(A30=A$2, A$2, "")
```

This is known as an *absolute row, relative column*. When dragged right column A will still shift to column B, column C, etc unless you lock the column as absolute as well (e.g. `$A$2`).